# How to set Browser's window using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change my browser's width and height using JavaScript and/or jQuery, is this possible?

Comment: you mean like resizing the browser? that's impossible

Comment: why in the world would you ever want to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://cybertext.com.au/tips_HTML_window_size.htm

In the head section:

```
<script>   
function changeScreenSize(w,h){       
    window.resizeTo( w,h )     
}
</script>
```

In the body tag

```
<body onload="changeScreenSize(500,300)">
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me... does this only work with popups or something?

Comment: its works for me..but when browser is with mutiple tabs its not working.

Comment: Good browsers don't allow resizing when multiple tabs are open because it is _really annoying_ for users. Really good browsers don't allow resizing except of windows opened via code.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that simple as you think. You should not generally try to resize user window, FF has an option to disable Javascript from resizing the browser window. Resizing the browser is not a good thing to do.

If you need a window of a specific size, open one of that size with the options to [window.open()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp).

Still if you need to do it, use [window.resizeTo()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_resizeto.asp).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Agreed, there is almost never an acceptable reason for resizing a user's browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
window.resizeTo(800, 600);
```

For more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.resizeTo